# getting Pages library from given URL

Tags: powershell, content-type, library, pages

I have a URL for subsite `mynews`: for example: `http://something.good/news/mynews` I want to add custom content type `'NewsCT'` to Pages library of this `mynews` subsite using powershell. How I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following PS script should help:

```
#Get site object and specify name of the library to look for in each site
$site = Get-SPSite http://something.good
$lookForList = "Pages"

#Walk through each site and change content types on the list specified
$siteA = $site.OpenWeb("http://something.good/news/mynews")

    write-host "Checking site:" $siteA.Title

    #Make sure content types are allowed on the list specified
    $docLibrary = $siteA.Lists[$lookForList]

    if ($docLibrary -ne $null)
    {
        $docLibrary.ContentTypesEnabled = $true
        $docLibrary.Update()

        #Add site content types to the list
        $ctToAdd = $siteA.ContentTypes["NewsCT"]
        $ct = $docLibrary.ContentTypes.Add($ctToAdd)
        write-host "Content type" $ct.Name "added to list" $docLibrary.Title
        $docLibrary.Update()
    }
    else
    {
        write-host "The list" $lookForList "does not exist in site" $siteA.Title
    }


#Dispose of the site object
$site.Dispose()
```